# How to use Crystal report in AspNet Core Mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-1.1

I have converted existing Erp Application from **Ap.net MVC** to **AspNetCore.Mvc**. I want to integrate crystal report to new application. I have added the reference of

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll
- CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll
- CrystalDecisions.Web.dll

But when I try to to use **Load, SetDataSource** functions of CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine ReportDocument , It shows compilation error as :

The type 'IDataReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

This is my code to load  Crystal report

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "rpt_EverestList.rpt"));
rd.SetDataSource(bUnits);
```

Is there any better option to use crystal report in AspNetCore.Mvc ?

Thanks & Regards
Sunij K

Comment: For what I remember it won't run on .net core ... you need to target your aspnet core application on full framework for it to work. Alternatively, you can try out .net core 2.0 preview. That may have the appropriate API to get this to work.